# Saving integers using SharedPreferances in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, int, sharedpreferences, save

I know how to save string from EditTexts on android but my problem is: I need to save the number of hours someone worked... 
This is a section of the code I have done... There is an error on the `toInt` method.

```
try {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("Hours",edit_hours.getText().toInt());
    editor.commit();

    trying_to_save.setText("SAVED!");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    trying_to_save.setText("I crashed");
}
```

Could you help me with my problem? 
Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I'm not aware there is a toInt() method in Android?

Try this:

```
editor.putInt("Hours",Integer.parseInt(edit_hours.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: will that give me an int when i take it out though because you saying change the edit text to a string?

Comment: The method toInt() simply does not exist, this is why you're getting a compiler error. On the other hand, getText() returns an Editable value and not a String value. You first need to get the string value (The actual text in the UI) using toString() and then convert it to Integer using Integer.parseInt(String)

Comment: Could you tell me how you call it back what I did was  type 'edit_hours.setText(settings.getInt("Hours", 0));' in the oncreat section but it crashed?

Comment: Dont worrie I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as an example :

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
EditTextPreference XXX = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("Hours");
XXX.setText(Integer.parseInt(hours));
```

Comment: How do you call it back later using this one?